# Photo Filter crashes app on iPod

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

I am applying filters to Image using GPU Image framework. These crashes my app on iPod Touch 4th generation. Below is my code for the same:

```
GPUImageSepiaFilter *selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:imgToFilter];
[self.imageCropperView setImage:filteredImage];
```

Same way, I am applying other filters. This is creating memory issues for iPod 4th Gen.

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Could u add the crash report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i know it is not fit in technical requirment of GPU Lib, take a look [Documentation](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

[image]

Comment: Is there any other library to apply such filters on images?

Comment: @spaleja: sorry , no idea about other lib.